# Ios - Google places SDK - Get places by location , not by Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-places

I'm trying to show places on the map. For some reason, I can't find a function that receives the places by location.

The only function that I see is the

> GMSPlacesClient

```
- (void)autocompleteQuery:(NSString *)query
                   bounds:(GMSCoordinateBounds * GMS_NULLABLE_PTR)bounds
                   filter:(GMSAutocompleteFilter * GMS_NULLABLE_PTR)filter
                 callback:(GMSAutocompletePredictionsCallback)callback;
```

The problem with this function, that it is searching only by text - I can insert filters, but i also need to insert a specific query/place to autocomplete.

What is the right way to retrieve places by the location of the map?

Comment: did you get any solution ?