# GoogleMaps iOS SDK Find name of a place at an arbitrary location

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-places

My app needs to auto-fill the address and place name (building name?) of the user's current location.

I'm using Core Location (`CLLocationManager`) to find the device's current location, and then reverse-geocoding (`CLGeocoder`) to get the address components (country, postal code, etc.).

*(I tried to use the GoogleMaps SDK reverse geocoder, but the address fields available seem to be sub-optimal for addresses in Japan. I would have to parse or split the `lines` field of `GMSAddress`...)*

Next, I need the place name. The SDK has a method to asynchronously query a list of most likely places for the device's current location:

`GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient().currentPlaceWithCallback()`

However, I need to:

1. Display the current location as a marker (`GMSMarker`) in a map view,
2. Let the user drag the marker to perform minor adjustments,
3. Re-search the place name of the new location where the user dropped the marker.

However, `GMSPlacesClient` does not seem to have a method to search the places around an *arbitrary* location (latitude/longitude), only the current one (it does has auto-complete, search by place ID, etc.).

Perhaps I'm approaching the API wrong, but it's a bit daunting...

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32767600/433373) seems to be about the same thing (but has no answers whatsoever...)

---

#### Edit:

I just found out there is a class named `GMSPlacePicker`, but it works as a modal view with it's own map view embedded and a very un-iOS-y visual design (think: Youtube.app or GoogleMaps Desktop Website), and I need to perform this on my existing `GMSMapView` (I have a layout I can not change).